# Sumar un Mes a una Fecha JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola amigos tengo una fecha que es 31/05/2019 en la cual quiero sumar un mes que seria 30/05/2019

```js
var fecha = "31/05/2019"
```

Comment: Es un tanto complejo ¿30 días, 31 días o sólo modificar el valor del mes? Tené en cuenta que el mes de Febrero suele cambiar mucho y sumar un mes no sería del todo confiable en ese sentido.

Comment: Si tienes razon entonces solo se sumaria si fuera mensual seria sumar 30 dias

Comment: @Alex podrías editar la pregunta, actualizando el título y poniendo esto que estás diciendo en la descripción? De lo contrario, las respuestas que recibas van a ser variadas y probablemente no sean lo que estás buscando

Comment: ¿Qué has intenado hasta el momento?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo asi

```
var enero = new Date(2019, 0, 25);
var febrero  = new Date(enero.setMonth(enero.getMonth()+1));
```

Recuerda que si utilizas el constructor antes mencionado los meses se empiezas a contar desde 0, no de 1. Ten cuidado con eso.

De igual forma puedes crear nuevos dates en JS con los siguientes constructores:

```
var d = new Date('2015-05-25');
var d = new Date('05/25/2015');
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero habría que hacer un `split()` de la fecha para obtener separados los días, meses y años, y luego sumando la cantidad de días.

```js
var fecha = '31/05/2019';
var fecha_split = fecha.split('/');

// seteo la fecha con los datos del string
var nueva_fecha = new Date(fecha_split[2], fecha_split[1], fecha_split[0]);
// agrego 30 días a la fecha ingresada y la vuelvo a setear
nueva_fecha.setDate(nueva_fecha.getDate() + 30);

// imprimo la fecha con 30 días más
console.log(nueva_fecha);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fuente: https://markhneedham.com/blog/2009/01/07/javascript-add-a-month-to-a-date/

```
var d = new Date(2019, 5-1, 31);
var r = new Date(new Date(d).setMonth(d.getMonth()+1));

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

La función [Date.setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) permite introducir valores fuera del rango habitual de un mes, siendo reajustado el mes y/o año en caso de que salirse de éstos:

```js
    fecha = new Date();
    fecha2 = new Date();
    dia = fecha.getDate();
    mes = fecha.getMonth()+1;// +1 porque los meses empiezan en 0
    anio = fecha.getFullYear();
    fecha2.setDate(fecha2.getDate() + 30);

    document.write(
      "Fecha actual: " +
      fecha.getDate() + "/" +
      (fecha.getMonth()+1) + "/" +
      fecha.getFullYear()
    );
    document.write(
      "<br>Fecha devolución: " +
      fecha2.getDate() + "/" +
      (fecha2.getMonth()+1) + "/" +
      fecha2.getFullYear()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera

```js
//Obteniendo la fecha actual
var fecha = new Date();
var fechaN = new Date(fecha.setMonth(fecha.getMonth() + 1));

//Para mostrar en consola o ya sea en un document.write usa toLocalDateString
console.log(fechaN.toLocaleDateString());


//Otra Forma, asignando una fecha
var fechaA = new Date("2019-05-31");
var fechaB = new Date(fechaA.setMonth(fechaA.getMonth() + 1));


//Para mostrar en consola o ya sea en un document.write toLocalDateString
console.log(fechaB.toLocaleDateString());
```

Espero te sea de utilidad